Alternative syntax/logic to avoid TS "Variable is used before being assigned."
I'm trying to write a generator function that would successively return pairs of previous and current values in an iterable.
function* prevCurrent<T>(iterable: Iterable<T>) {
    let head = true
    let previous: T
    for (const current of iterable) {
        if (head) {
            previous = current
            head = false
            continue
        }
        yield [previous, current]
        previous = current
    }
}

and used as follows:
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
for (const pair of prevCurrent(arr)) {
    console.log(pair)
}
// [1, 2]
// [2, 3]

However, on the yield line, TypeScript reports:
Variable 'previous' is used before being assigned.

Apparently the static analysis doesn't recognize that the yield can only be reached in the second iteration of the for-of, with previous already set.
I can easily get around this with the ! operator. But is there an alternative syntax or logic I could use that static analysis would accept?

The compiler doesn't understand that there's any relationship between head and previous. You could package them both in a single variable like prevHead of a discriminated union type like {head: true} | {head: false, previous: T}. But once you do that you can collapse it to just undefined | { previous: T }. Indeed if you knew that T could not accept undefined then you'd just collapse it all the way to undefined | T... meaning that you'd use previous alone and not head at all.
But assuming that undefined extends T is possible, then we can use something equivalent to undefined | { previous: T } to distinguish between the first run through the loop and a run after an undefined value.  Let's do that and rename the variable/property:
function* prevCurrent<T>(iterable: Iterable<T>) {
  let previous: { val: T } | undefined;
  for (const current of iterable) {
    if (!previous) {
      previous = { val: current }
      continue
    }
    yield [previous.val, current]
    previous.val = current
  }
}

Here the variable is just previous and it's either undefined or is an object with a val property of type T. That compiles because now there's no way to even represent an invalid state.
Playground link to code

Consider creating the iterator yourself:
function* prevCurrent<T>(iterable: { [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T> }) {
    const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    const { value, done } = iterator.next();
    if (done) return;
    let previous: T = value;
    for (const current of iterator) {
        yield [previous, current]
        previous = current
    }
}


I can't use for-of on the iterator directly, per TypeScript: Type 'Iterator<T, any, undefined>' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator. playground. But I guess I could use a do-while loop.

@ZevSpitz Ah right you'd need something stronger than Iterable<T>
